ON1 Photo RAW 2024 2nd monitor follow active photo
I just started using ON1 Photo RAW 2024. It's great, but there seems to be an issue:
When using 2 monitors in Dual mode - detail view on 1st and thumbnail view on the 2nd -  the 2nd one follows the active photo (blue outline) and advances the grid forward if a photo after the last one visible is selected (using cursor keys). But as soon as an edit is made to an active photo, the grid on the 2nd monitor stops advancing until I select a photo on the grid and continue.
No sure if this is a bug. I had a look in the settings, but couldn't find anything related.
